# How to add links in dropdown options in Angular -Html? <a> tag is not working after select an option in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu

I tried to add links inside dropdown option.

Edit : The Issue is `<a>` is not working after any option is selected

**But If i right click on any option and select "Open link in new tab", that will go to that link. so my link is working**

plese Somebody help me to find the issue

This is my code

```
            <nb-select
              placeholder = "Links"
              nbTooltip="Select rows"
              nbTooltipPlacement="top"
            >
              <nb-option
                [nbTooltip]="'Link ' + (i + 1)"
                nbTooltipPlacement="top"
                value = {{i+1}}
                style="color: blue;"
                >

                <a [href]="/some-external-links-here
              "
              target="_blank"
              class="text-decoration-none"> Link {{i+1}} </a>
              </nb-option>
            </nb-select>
```

Comment: In Angular, you navigate using [routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)", e.g.`<a routerLink="/first-component" routerLinkActive="active">First Component</a>`, not href. BTW if you use `[href]="/some-links-here"` the `[` `]` makes that Angular search a variable in your .ts (called /some-links-here) if you want a external link is `href="/some-link-here"` (without brakets)

Comment: @Eliseo when i right click on any option and select `Open link in new tab`,then my link works. My issue is when i select any option, that link is not selected

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
  <nb-select
              placeholder = "Links"
              nbTooltip="Select rows"
              nbTooltipPlacement="top"
            >
              <nb-option
                *ngFor="let x of deal.holidays; let i = index"
                [nbTooltip]="'Link ' + (i + 1)"
                nbTooltipPlacement="top"
                style="color: blue;"
                >

                <a [attr.href]="/some-links-here
              "
              target="_blank"
              class="text-decoration-none"> Link {{i+1}} </a>
              </nb-option>
            </nb-select>
```

> <a [attr.href]="/some-links-here"

If you want add target attribute also.

Comment: My issue is, after i select an option, the option is selected but `<a> </a>` is not working. There is no issue with `href`

Comment: Because <a> element resides inside nb-option try to change the order. make nb-option as child to <a> element